# ¿Como puedo cargar en un <select> la opcion anteriormente seleccionada dentro de un formulario de modificar en Laravel 6?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap, select, laravel-6

Lo que quiero es que en mi formulario de modificar en laravel se cargue la opcion o **value** anteriormente puesto en un **select**.
ya he logrado recuperar dichos valores llamando los datos a mi modal que estan originalmente en una tabla utilizando el data-whatever que nos ofrece bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/) he incogiendo todo en un json.

mi select al que quiero pasarle el valor escogido anterirmente que me viene de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El boton que abre mi modal y esta dentro de una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como paso los los valores a mi modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido. Para tener más posibilidades de respuesta, deberías poner el código en texto y no en imágenes.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante revises el documento [ask], te sugerimos agregar el còdigo como texto para que sea visible para todos los miembros de la cominidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno mientras buscaba una solucion a mi problema me di cuenta que lo que debia hacer era comparar el dato que viene de mi tabla el cual estoy extrayendo con el data.whatever y hacer que se seleccione la opcion que sea igual al dato de mi tabla (dato tipo varchar Unico).

Lo cual nos da como resutado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

explico:

selecciono el elemento select option del Dom que quiero que me cargue la opcion anteriormente puesta y recorro los options con el metodo .each() y posteriormente toma el text de cada option y lo compara con la variable que viene de mi tabla y lo selecciona.

Espero que les sirva un saludo. ;)

Comment: Por favor lee [Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes…](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/92278) y [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)